# How to use a payable function with a ERC20 token with web3 v1

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I have a function in my Ethereum smart contract with the following interface

```
// submitting a review requires a payment
function addReview(string review) public payable
```

Using web3 v1 invoking this function would be something like this

```
contract.methods.addReview(review).send({
 from: accounts[0],
 value: SOME_AMOUNT_IN_ETH
})
```

How can I invoke this function with a different ERC20 token rather than using Ether?

Comment: `payable` has to do with ether. ERC20 tokens are smart contracts... to transfer tokens, you have to invoke the `transfer` or `transferFrom` methods on the token smart contract.

Comment: sounds like I'm missing something in my thinking "to transfer tokens, you have to invoke the transfer or transferFrom methods on the token smart contract" I don't fully understand this statement. Do you now if a good tutorial/description of how to use ERC20 tokens?

Comment: These are from my blog: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/26/what-is-an-ethereum-token/ and https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/30/writing-an-erc20-token-contract/

Answer (score 0):

If your payable function is `foo` and takes 1 parameter and you want to send `x` amount of ether and `contract` is the contract you want to refer to, you would invoke it like that:

`contract.foo.value(x).(param1)(msg.sender);`

Comment: I was trying to see if it's possible to send an amount in my token not in ether, which sounds like that's not possible. right?

Comment: No, in this case it is not possible to do it. You have to make a call to the ERC-20 contract to transfer it. Though something similar would be to add some allowance, in coins(ERC-20 token support this), for your other contract, before you call `addReview` and then when you call it you can use `TransferFrom` from inside the `addReview`  function to transfer the coins. Again it is not the same thing but, in my opinion, it is as close as you can get.